# htaccess regex directory to variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

I need to make a 301 redirect for certain URLs from directory to variable.

EXAMPLE:

```
    http://domain.com/es/stackoverflow --> http://domain.com/stackoverflow?lang=es
    http://domain.com/he/stackoverflow --> http://domain.com/stackoverflow?lang=he
```

As it is now I have a "directory structure" for each language and it's making seperate URLs for the same page, it just switches the language.

I just want to add the language identifier at the end.

The thing is not every page had those language identifiers after the tld/

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1
```

Comment: @Lost305, no need just click the tick to accept the Answer ;-?