# Regular expression for .htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have edited **all** urls in my website, an **example** is one below (it doesn't have to be under calipers directory) (Also the number of underscores are not constant)

> .com/Calipers/Insize_1108_1_2

to

> .com/Calipers/Insize-1108-1-2

so only 1 character is changed in the urls, how should I modify my .htaccess ?

Currently my htaccess does not containt anything other than my cms default settings as below.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit: This is what I tried to to and it did not work.**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)[_]([^/]+)$ $1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ¿How is your .htaccess file now? It would help to know what's being  modified.

Comment: @bukfixart I am tring to learn regex, but it requires some experience to write it correctly at first, so I am looking for help.

Comment: I think your rewrite rule should be something like this `RewriteRule ^_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$  Calipers/Insize-$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L]`. I just modified the regex, but didn't test it.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA,  the number of underscores are unknown, plus the directories also.

Comment: ¿Is there a minimum and a maximum?

Comment: Well the issue arrised from this, we were creating seo friendly urls for our products (which is the title of the product seperated by underscore) and we realised that it would be better to use - instead. So I executed an SQL Query to rename all friendly seo urls to for the whole website to be using - instead of _. So there are 1200 urls  renamed, and I just need to correct those urls so that google will reindex them. I guess this means no max min limit.

Comment: In other words, there can be up to 1200 underscores in a single URL or that never happens and only a limited number is included in each link?

Comment: 1200 is the number of URLs that I renamed in my website, each product or category or whatever has its own url and total about 1200 urls. The number of underscores in each of these urls is not unlimited, it depends on how long the title of the product.

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch 301 (/Calipers/Insize)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)$ $1-$2-$3-$4

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

untested yet,

also see here: [htaccess regex directory to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747296/htaccess-regex-directory-to-variable)

#### edit

Your regex `^([^/]+)[_]([^/]+)$` doesn't match your url ".com/Calipers/Insize_1108_1_2"

With `^` the start of the string is marked. It would be better to look from the end don't touch the begin.

This results in

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [R=301,L]
```

what isn't very different from my first solution.

It groups the three numbers at the end (with `(\d+)` for each one) and takes the rest until start (with `(.*)`).

Comment: Please check the last edit part that I added to my question, I am tring to create a bulk redirect regular expression.

Comment: @bukfixart  I think back reference 1 is pointing to the wrong group: `(/Calipers/Insize)`.